# Rails rake specified migrate file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, database-migration

I have rake migrate and generate all tables.

Now,I want to change a table,but I don't want to rake a change migrate.I just want to delete the table and execute the command again:

```
rake db:migrate
```

But nothing happened.

So I want to know,what should  I do when I rake to generate the new table after I delete the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you want to change a migration with timestamp : 201311211234 and you just want to make  changes to this particular migration without affecting other tables then do

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=201311211234
```

Then make change on that migration file

then just do

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=201311211234
```

Second option is to delete the row for version 201311211234 from `schema_migrations` table and then run `rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 1):

If you are running changes you should use:

```
rake db:rollback
... make changes ...
rake db:migrate
```

To fix it now you will have to delete the last entry in your `schema_migrations` table (since you didn't run a rollback I'm guessing).

Answer (score 1):

```
rake db:migrate
```

Updates the schema file. When you write migration files, make sure to push code in `self.down`. So when you run `rake db:rollback`, the below commands are executed. You can change the schema file manually to fix this issue.

You can also run specific migrations from console but that should be avoided in any case rather use the timestamp to run it from terminal.